# Push code to Heroku from Jenkins is not working with error as "App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-xxxx.." . But in manual is working

Tags: jenkins, github, heroku

Am trying to generate build in Heroku with Jenkins and github. While push to heroku facing following error.
**ERROR: Failed to push branch master to herokubackend
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git push https://git.heroku.com/xxxxxxxx.git HEAD:master -f" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Compressing source files... done.[K
remote: Building source:[K
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz**

But when we push manually it works. Anyone can help on this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Each Heroku buildpack has a set of requirements to allow running it.
The python one requires requirements.txt, setup.py or Pipfile: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect

The error you're getting means the detection command failed because none of those files were found.

Is Jenkins modifying something within your repository? Deleting some files? Pushing only a subpart of it?